# Assigning parameters to variables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure:

```
alter procedure teste2_parts 
    (@date datetime null,
     @tableNameOrig varchar, 
     @tableNameDest varchar) 
as
    declare 
        @tableNameOrigName varchar(50), 
        @tableNameDestName varchar(50);
 
    set @tableNameOrigName = substring(@tableNameOrig, charindex('.', @tableNameOrig) + 1, len(@tableNameOrig))

    print @tableNameOrigName;
    print @tableNameOrig;
```

However when I print the variables I got:

```
o
o
```

I am calling the stored procedure like this:

```
exec teste2_parts null, 'ods.teste_parts_target', 'ods.teste_parts_target_v2'
```

Where is the problem?

EDIT: As I didn't know that the problem was the length of varchar on header, I could not search with the right terms.

Comment: You declared your parameter as varchar without a length.  It should be @tableNameOrig varchar(50).

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Better yet, use `NVARCHAR(257)`, as this accounts for the maximum length of schema name + dot  + table name (assuming `ods` is a schema). Also, use `PARSENAME` for splitting schema and table, not manual code, which can't handle escaped identifiers correctly.

Comment: Or perhaps better, you might consider providing the values for the (database), schema, and object separately, and then you can use the data type `sysname`.

Comment: Hmm, if the OP *is* passing potentionally escaped object names (like `[This is a [poorly]] named database].[And.Schema].[Why would anyone do this?]`, @JeroenMostert, then *technically* the OP would need an `nvarchar(517)` (`2 * 258 + 1`) for schema and object name.

Comment: @Larnu: or maybe times 4 if it's a remote object? :P Yeah, I considered only the simplest case, and passing the parts in separate parameters is a better idea, if it's an option (whether it is will depend on where the identifier is coming from; writing client-side code to parse things is also a pain).

Comment: Yeah, I personally find that passing parts is just easier, @JeroenMostert ; you can define each part as a `sysname` and then don't have to try and parse the name into parts from a potentially non-escaped value. Sure, it results in more parameters, but it makes dealing with the both the full object path and parts of it much easier.

Comment: `sp_rename` uses `nvarchar(776)` datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a length for the procedures variables:

```
alter procedure teste2_parts 
(@date datetime null,
 @tableNameOrig varchar(250), 
 @tableNameDest varchar(250))
```

as ....